# Design idea on how to make a watchdog program to be aware and handle an exit code of one of it's wards

Tags: c++, exit-code

In my project, I have a several applications running.

One of them is a 'watchdog' application - an application that checks every time interval in an infinite loop weather the other applications (wards) are still running. In case a ward is no longer running - the watchdog restarts it.

I now want to extend functionality of the watchdog so that he will somehow become aware not only if a program stops running, but what exit code it returned when it did, and then act according to exit code.

Comment: Is the watchdog allowed to be the one that starts the wards in the first place? Or do the wards have to be run some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already be checking whether the ward has terminated with a [wait function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069.aspx) like `WaitForMultipleObjects`, called on a handle to the ward process (which you acquired via `CreateProcess` or `OpenProcess`). Once you've detected a terminated process, pass that same process handle to [`GetExitCodeProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683189.aspx) and it will tell you the exit code.